# "Spider thread" in Portuguese

Tags: tradução-inglês, palavra-para-ideia

What would you call a spider thread in Portuguese?

I know that spider web is *teia de aranha*.

Could it be *fio de aranha*?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not an entomologist and this how I would phrase it, in general, **as a layman**:

I'd call both of them "teia de aranha" (or simply **"teia"**), with a small difference between them. A spider web, in the singular, is more likely to be preceded by a determiner and I therefore would say **"(uma/aquela/essa/esta) teia de aranha"**. Then again, for "spider thread/silk" I wouldn't use the preceding determiner at all and would say **"teia de aranha"**.

e.g.

- "Olha ali, **uma teia de aranha**."
- "Vê só o tamanho **daquela teia**."
- "O local estava cheio de teias de aranha" (plural)

compare with:

- (a) "O que é isso no teu braço?" (b) "Ah, é **teia de aranha**."
- "Esse fio que grudou no meu rosto parece **teia de aranha**."

A detailist, however, would make it a point to say **"um fio de teia de aranha"**.

Answer (score 2):

I'm Brazilian and I always say "**teia de aranha**" for spider thread and spider web.

"**Fio de aranha**" or "**Fio de teia de aranha**" or "**seda de aranha**" aren't wrong, but are not as common.

Comment: Nós falamos mais frequentemente de teias que de fios indivifuais. Mas dizes *teia de aranha* se for um fio só? Também já vi simplesmente *fio de teia*.

Comment: Sim... dizemos teia de aranha para um fio e algumas vezes fio de teia.

Como o Brasil é grande é possível que em algum lugar seja mais comum dizer um "fio de aranha", mas pelo menos em São Paulo ou Rio de Janeiro  é mais comum o termo teia de aranha seja para fio ou para a teia própriamente dita.

Comment: Eu sou de Portugal. Se eu me quiser referir só a um fio, não digo *teia*. Mas mais depressa diria *fio de teia de aranha* ou só *fio de teia* que *fio de aranha*. Ou em contexto,  simplesmente fio: *a aranha desceu por um fio*.

Comment: @Jacinto eu também.